# Setting up Internet Access on Trimble R8 for RTK-GPS Corrections w/o using a Controller or Trimble Access Software

Tags: trimble, rtkgps+

I am trying to set up direct Internet access for a Trimble R8s receiver in order to retrieve (RTK) position corrections in real-time from our state geodetic survey's CORS network. By direct Internet access I am referring to a hardware configuration that includes only the R8s and an accompanying Verizon JetPack MiFi wireless hotspot device-- there is to be no controller or other supporting PC, or Trimble's Access Software App., involved. The receiver would retrieve corrections by directly linking to the CORS caster (using the state-provided URL, port#, mount point, and login credentials) via the JetPack, downloading those corrections, applying them to the raw x-y-z data internally, and then streaming the corrected coordinates to another (non-PC) device.

For some context: The R8s - JetPack set up is to be installed on a remotely operated hydrographic survey boat. The non-PC device, the recipient of the corrected GPS data, will be a single-beam sonar unit that's also installed on the boat. There is limited space on-board to stow a supporting computer.

I am able to log into the R8 via bluetooth and a web browser (thru a PC running Windows 10) and reach the configuration interface, but from here I'm at a loss as to what to do next to establish communications to the JetPack. A bunch of Google searching, and a series of unanswered appeals for help sent to our Trimble regional business partner over the past several days has done nothing to get me closer to a connection. Does anyone out there know:

1. If this can even be done? (The Trimble docs suggest that this is possible, but I'm beginning to wonder), and
2. if so, then could I trouble someone to tell me how next to proceed?

Comment: The R8 supports LTE (via SIMCard?)  and has Data storage: 56 MB internal memory, 960 hours of raw observables... correct? then transmit on the usb (with a transmitter?) https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32776195073.html

Comment: I can vouch for the data storage capacities you mention for the R8, but I'm not so familiar with its communications support (i.e., SIMCard and LTE). That's not to suggest that such support doesn't exist, but only to admit my own ignorance in regard. I'll have a look at your USB transmit(er) idea. Thanks.

Comment: I'm familiar with earlier Trimble R8 receivers but I don't know anything about the JetPack so I can't answer your question directly (that's why this is a comment).  I believe you could do what you want easily if you binned the JetPack and used a cheap (but Verizon-approved) Android phone instead, Trimble's GNSS Status would probably talk to R8S via Bluetooth and do what you want or you could access the R8S WebUI via WiFi in a browser but that's more complicated.  If changing to a mobile phone is an option, edit the original question and someone is sure to help you!